# Ignore dependency log4j.properties

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, wildfly

I have a web application deployed on WildFly 10. After adding a new Maven dependency to my application, logging stopped working. Investigating, I've found that the new dependency includes a `log4j.properties` in its JAR, and I guess this is causing the logging to screw up.

I cannot delete the file from the JAR, since every time my project compiles it would come back. I need WildFly to manage the logging properties, so adding an additional `log4j.properties` isn't an option (it would be if it can be configured to fallback to WildFly defaults, but I don't know if this is possibile).

How can I ignore a dependency's `log4j.properties` or override it with WildFly's settings?

Comment: Report it as a bug to the jar's maintainer.

Comment: Done, but in the meanwhile I'd like to find a workaround! For reference: https://github.com/marytts/marytts/issues/711

Comment: Have you tried replacing it in the jar with an empty properties file? i.e. one that doesn't change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app does not use is own log4j properties file or xml, you are best just disabling the per-deployment logging configuration option on wildfly, then any will be ignored

Comment: Thank you Will T, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude Logging module from you jar.

```
dependencies {

compile group : 'com.chapter1' name: 'common.all',       version: '1.0.001'{

       exclude( // here u can exclude that module... )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WildFly 10 you can set the `use-deployment-logging-config` on the logging subsystem to `false` which will skip processing any logging configuration files. Do note this will skip processing on all deployments.